# Optimizing n-body simulation

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the n-body algorithm, I have seen that the most expensive function is this:

```
real3 bodyBodyInteraction(real iPosx, real iPosy, real iPosz, 
                          real jPosx, real jPosy, real jPosz, real jMass)
{
  real rx, ry, rz;

  rx = jPosx - iPosx;
  ry = jPosy - iPosy;
  rz = jPosz - iPosz;

  real distSqr = rx*rx+ry*ry+rz*rz;
  distSqr += SOFTENING_SQUARED;


   real s = jMass / POW(distSqr,3.0/2.0); //very expensive

  real3 f;
  f.x = rx * s;
  f.y = ry * s;
  f.z = rz * s;

  return f;
}
```

Using perf record I can see the division is the most expensive instruction and this one have a O(n^2) complexity, but I don't really know how to optimize it.

Comment: Try this: `y / x**(3/2) = y * x**(-3/2) = y * x**(-1) * x**(-1/2) = y * (1/x) * rsqrt(x)`, where `**` denotes exponentiation. Your compiler may or may not offer `rsqrt()` as it is currently an extension (to be included in a future standard). Check the documentation. Reciprocal 1/x should be cheap when you compile with a "fast math" switch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
```

into

```cpp
for(int i=0;  i<N;i++)
for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++)
```

Restructure to take advantage of [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) operators, this can quadruple your throughput.

Use [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/) to parallelize the loops either across your CPU or by offloading to your GPU (OpenMP 4.5+).

Learn about the [Barnes-Hut algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation), which groups particles to achieve *O(N log N)* complexity (down from your *O(N^2)*).

Comment: Where can I find a more extensive explanation?

Comment: @Chariot: I think Google is the best way to go there. Your question is very broad with many possible answers, so asking here is not the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite a nice one to SIMD. It's worth noting that this:

```cpp
real s = jMass / POW(distSqr,3.0/2.0);
```

can be refactored into this if you negate the power: (removes a division)

```cpp
real s = jMass * POW(distSqr, -3.0/2.0);
```

Its now worth noting that you can remove the call to pow completely here, since you are dealing with a very simple exponent. so...

```cpp
real s = jMass * std::sqrt(distSqr) / (distSqr * distSqr);
```

If you know your laws of powers, you can do an additional refactor step here:

```cpp
real s = jMass / (std::sqrt(distSqr) * distSqr);
```

Now with any luck, your compiler *should* hopefully be performing this transformation for you already (you'll need -O2 and -ffast-math typically). Example:
https://godbolt.org/z/8YqFYA

The reason this is nice, is that now you have removed a cmath call from your code completely. This makes it very easy to drop to something like simd, and extremely easy if you happpen to be using clang or gcc. e.g.

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

typedef __m256 real;
struct real3 { real x, y, z; };

// i had to make up a value
const __m256 SOFTENING_SQUARED = _mm256_set1_ps(1.23f); 

real3 bodyBodyInteraction(real iPosx, real iPosy, real iPosz, 
                          real jPosx, real jPosy, real jPosz, real jMass)
{
  real rx, ry, rz;

  rx = jPosx - iPosx;
  ry = jPosy - iPosy;
  rz = jPosz - iPosz;

  real distSqr = rx*rx+ry*ry+rz*rz;
  distSqr += SOFTENING_SQUARED;

  real s = jMass / (_mm256_sqrt_ps(distSqr) * distSqr);

  real3 f;
  f.x = rx * s;
  f.y = ry * s;
  f.z = rz * s;

  return f;
}
```

And in godbolt:

https://godbolt.org/z/JTCwm-

Comment: I have tried this real s = jMass * POW(distSqr, -3.0/2.0); but the compiler does the division equally